# CommanderJS - validate argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Given the following `cli` configuration, we can validate the arguments passed by simply putting an imperative control inside the action handler...

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var program = require('commander');

program
  .command('greet <person>')
  .action((person, cmd) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${person}`);
  })

program.parse(process.argv)
```

However, I was wondering if there were actual apis to do so:

```
program.command('greet <Giuseppe|Mick|Bob>');
```

So that `commanderjs` would automatically throw if arguments are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The philosophy for `command` arguments is that they can be anything, thus have to be handled in the `action`.

If you want a finite set of *options*, you might want to use [`option`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#regular-expression).

A workaround to generically handle this case would be to use [git-style sub-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#git-style-sub-commands):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// main entry point for the program, let's call it mycmd

const program = require('commander');

program.command('greet', 'greets someone');

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Then have the `greet` command file:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// entry point for `greet` subcommand, named mycmd-greet

const program = require('commander');

// declare all available cases
// (you could also obviously reuse the same function as the action callback)
program
.command('giuseppe')
.action(() => {
  console.log("Hi Giu!");
});
program
.command('mick')
.action(() => {
  console.log("Hey Micky!");
});
program
.command('bob')
.action(() => {
  console.log("That's my Bobby!");
});

// handle `greet` failures here in one shot
program
.command('*')
.action((x) => {
  console.log(`Sorry, I don't know no ${x}.`);
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, you can do it like this:

```
program
  .addArgument(new commander.Argument('<drink-size>', 'drink cup size').choices(['small', 'medium', 'large']))
```

see documentation of commander at https://github.com/tj/commander.js/#more-configuration-1